# Implement an IntervalSlider

Tags: plotting, dynamic, slider

I do not know how to incorporate an `IntervalSlider` in the code below in order to change the two instances of the t-domain (in the `NDSolve` and `ParametricPlot` commands). My code is an excerpt from a phase plane plotter. I have tried to use the example from the Documentation but to no avail. Can someone show how this can be done?

```
DynamicModule[{g = {}, p = {}, dx, dy, sol, x0, y0},
 dx := 1 - x y;  dy = x - y^3;
 sol[{dx_, dy_}, {x0_, y0_}] := {u[t], v[t]} /. 
   Quiet@First@
     NDSolve[{u'[t] == dx /. {x -> u[t], y -> v[t]}, 
       v'[t] == dy /. {x -> u[t], y -> v[t]}, u[0] == x0, v[0] == y0, 
       WhenEvent[Abs[v[t]] > 2, "StopIntegration"]}, {u, v}, {t, -10, 10},               
Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
 Column[{
   Dynamic@ClickPane[
     Show[
      Quiet@
       ParametricPlot[g, {t, -10, 10}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
        ImageSize -> 450, PlotStyle -> Black],
      Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]],
     (AppendTo[g, sol[{dx, dy}, #]]; AppendTo[p, #]) &]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: I want the IntervalSlider to change the t-values -10 and 10 in the two instances of {t,-10,10}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[
    {g = {}, p = {}, dx, dy, sol, x0, y0, td = {-10, 10}}
  , dx := 1 - x y; dy = x - y^3
  ; sol[{dx_, dy_}, {x0_, y0_}] := {u[t], v[t]} /. Quiet@First@
     NDSolve[{u'[t] == dx /. {x -> u[t], y -> v[t]}, 
       v'[t] == dy /. {x -> u[t], y -> v[t]}, u[0] == x0, v[0] == y0, 
       WhenEvent[Abs[v[t]] > 2, "StopIntegration"]}, {u, v}, {t, -10, 
       10}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"
    ]
  ; Column[
        { ClickPane[  Dynamic@Show[Quiet @ ParametricPlot[
              g, {t, ##}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> None 
            , Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450, PlotStyle -> Black
          ] & @@  td, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]], (AppendTo[g, 
       sol[{dx, dy}, #]]; AppendTo[p, #]) &]

   , IntervalSlider[Dynamic@td, {-10, 10}, Method -> "Push"]
   }]]
```

[image]

Comment: excellent solution!

Comment: What is the role of  `& @@  td` that follows the ParametricPlot command?

Comment: @Stephen Take a look at `Apply`. Shortly `foo[##]& @@ {b, a, r}` evaluates to `foo[b, a, r]`.